# Implementing a registerClass like behavior in Swift using generics

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, metatype

I have a tricky question to figure out. But I'm not able to find out a specific solution for it.

Before explaining the goal this is the code I created so far.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

    init()
    func parse()

}

class MyService<T : SomeProtocol> {

    var clazz : T.Type?

    func registerClass(clazz: T.Type) {
        self.clazz = clazz
    }

    func doWork() {

        if let clazz = self.clazz {

            let clazzInstance = clazz.init()
            clazzInstance.parse()

        }
    }

}

class MyClass : SomeProtocol {

    required init() { }

    func parse() {
        print("My Class parsing")
    }

}

class MyClass2 : SomeProtocol {

    required init() { }

    func parse() {
        print("My Class2 parsing")
    }

}
```

The above code can be used like the following:

```
let myService = MyService<MyClass>()
myService.registerClass(MyClass.self)
myService.doWork()

let myService2 = MyService<MyClass2>()
myService2.registerClass(MyClass2.self)
myService2.doWork()
```

So, in order to explain a little bit about the context. I have a service, `MyService` in this case. I can create an instance of that service in order to perform some work. The service does a simple job: it receives some parameters and returns some JSON data. Based on the class I registered in the service (see `registerClass` method), the service will create an instance of that class and then it will invoke some method on it (in fact the class is registered conforms to `SomeProtocol` protocol). Here it is important to note that the code responsible to create the service class can choose to register or not a class. The `clazz` property is optional, as you can see.

At this point, this is what I would like to achieve: removing the `T` at the class level and moving it at the `registerClass` level. In other words, like the following:

```
class MyService {

    var clazz : T.Type?

    func registerClass<T : SomeProtocol>(clazz: T.Type) {
        self.clazz = clazz
    }

    // the other code here

}
```

Based on this assumption, the usage should become:

```
let myService = MyService()
// I can choose to call this method in order to register a class into it
myService.registerClass(MyClass.self) 
myService.doWork()
```

Obviously if I do in this manner, this is the error I receive for the `class` property within `MyService` class.

> Use of undeclared type 'T'

Any suggestions to reach my goal? Thanks.

P.S. Feel free to modify the title. I haven't found a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is for `clazz` to conform to a protocol then there is no need for generics. This might do what you want:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
  init()
  func parse()
}

class MyService {
  var clazz : SomeProtocol?

  func registerClass(clazz: SomeProtocol) {
    self.clazz = clazz
  }

  func doWork() {
    clazz?.parse()
  }
}

class MyClass : SomeProtocol {
  required init() { }

  func parse() {
    print("My Class parsing")
  }
}

class MyClass2 : SomeProtocol {
  required init() { }

  func parse() {
    print("My Class2 parsing")
  }
}

let myService = MyService()
myService.registerClass(MyClass())
myService.doWork()

let myService2 = MyService()
myService2.registerClass(MyClass2())
myService2.doWork()
```